# Unable to download files from SEC.Gov using Java

Tags: java

I am trying to download files from SEC.gov, but the following code fails to download the file.  All the files downloaded using this code is of 1 KB.

```
URL Url = null;

try {
    Url= new URL("http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/769397/000076939716000079/0000769397-16-000079-xbrl.zip");

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}

String fullPathFileName = "D:\\0000769397-16-000079-xbrl.zip";

File destinationFile = new File(fullPathFileName);

try {
    FileUtils.copyURLToFile(Url, destinationFile);

} catch (IOException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

}
```

If I use this same code to download from another site, it works.  I have also tried the copuURLToFile method with connection timeout and read timeout.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I am not getting any error.  All files downloaded are of 1 KB in size and is unreadable.  I have tried downloading zip and XBRL XML files from SEC.Gov with the same result.  For example: http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/769397/000076939716000079/adsk-20160430.xml

Comment: What is in the 1k file you get? If you have Cygwin installed, what does `file ...` on the download say?

Comment: I tried this and downloaded this file - http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1108524/000119312509180950/crm-20090731.xml  and reproduced this error.  I got a 1 KB file back and I used cygwin file and go this:   file crm-20090731_file_1.xml
crm-20090731_file_1.xml: gzip compressed data, from Unix

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `FileUtils.copyURLToFile()` is that it doesn't give you any information about what it's doing. Try the `wget` utility from the command line:

```
wget http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/769397/000076939716000079/0000769397-16-000079-xbrl.zip
--2016-10-18 21:47:31--  http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/769397/000076939716000079/0000769397-16-000079-xbrl.zip
Resolving www.sec.gov... 104.82.85.98
Connecting to www.sec.gov|104.82.85.98|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/769397/000076939716000079/0000769397-16-000079-xbrl.zip [following]
--2016-10-18 21:47:32--  https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/769397/000076939716000079/0000769397-16-000079-xbrl.zip
Connecting to www.sec.gov|104.82.85.98|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify www.sec.gov's certificate, issued by `/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust SSL CA - G3':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to www.sec.gov insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

It's likely you got a similar error message. Try opening your 1KB file in Notepad.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this great tip!  You have nailed the problem using wget.  HTTP was getting redirected to HTTPS and copyURLToFile was failing.  When I changed my URL to HTTPS, it started working.  The good folks at SEC had answered my query and had asked me to try HTTPS.